# How to estimate the derivatives of Green function?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

The Green function of a domain in the plane is defined to be

$$G_D(x,y)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\log(|x-y|)+h(x,y)$$

And h is given by a harmonic function

$$\Delta_x h(x,y)=0$$

With boundary condition

$$h(x,y)|_{x\in \partial D}=-\frac{1}{2\pi}\log(|x-y|)$$

How to get the estimates of derivatives:

$$|\nabla G_D (x,y)|\leq C(D)|x-y|^{-1}$$
$$|\nabla^2 G_D (x,y)|\leq C(D)|x-y|^{-2}$$

Actually it remains to estimate the derivatives of the harmonic function h.

Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: The harmonic corrector $h$ is smooth so $\nabla h$ and $\nabla^2h$ are bounded by constants $C(D)$ (unless the domain is pathological).

Comment: @Jeff Does h smooth to boundary?

Comment: Provided the boundary of $D$ is $C^2$ (I suppose $C^{1,\alpha}$ should be fine), $\nabla h$ and $\nabla^2h$ will be continuous up to the boundary and you have nice global estimates. For less regular boundaries, $h$ may not be smooth up to the boundary.

Comment: @Jeff How to reach this?  I mean why is $\nabla h$ continuous near boundary.

Comment: There is some deep elliptic PDE theory behind this--it is certainly not obvious. You can find results like this in Gilbarg & Trudinger http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-3-642-96379-7